# Using RedirectStandardInput in Process Start in C# for console application, disables output in that same console started

Tags: notepad++, visual-studio, console, c#

I wrote a console application in C#, it is a parser for some language that translates the input file into XML. The parser gets it's input from the standard input(Keyboard) and it contains the name of the file i want to parse. The output of the parsing is then displayed in the console.
Now i am trying to write a plugin(C#) for notepad++, and in it when the user clicks on a button, it should open a window for the console application(parser) that i wrote and send it the name of the currently open tab in notepad++, all of this is already implemented and working. I use Process.Start to start the process of the parser, When i use Start with no other settings it starts regularly and opens the console and i can type whatever i want, but when i use

```
pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
pProcess.Start();
StreamWriter stdInputWriter = pProcess.StandardInput;
stdInputWriter.WriteLine(moduleName);
```

in order to send the process the wanted module, it automatically disables the output of the console in the same window, and i can only retrieve the output by redirecting standard output.

is there a way around this issue, i want to be able to use the parser as a console and also as a plugin.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the console program to allow the input file name on the command line. Without any command line arguments the program works as now and reads from standard input. Then make the plugin start the program with the equivalent of `consoleProgram.exe /inputFile name-of-input-file` and there is no need to redirect he standard input.

A simple console program to do this would start as:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string inputFileName;
    if (args.Count() == 0)
    {
        inputFileName = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else if (args.Count() == 1)
    {
        inputFileName = args[0];
    }
    else
    {
        ... Grumble about unexpected arguments;
    }
```

Then in the plugin add something like

```
pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "the-file-name";
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments?view=netframework-4.8) for more info.

Comment: but how will i send the process the name of the file i want it to parse? Should i create a temp file then the console app can read it and delete it after?
can i use this?
```
stdInputWriter.WriteLine("c edm_ti");
```

Comment: @Rany, I assumed that you knew about `Process.StartInfo` since you were already using it. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments?view=netframework-4.8 . Passing the name via another file could be done but that would be the wrong approach.